# Keep focus on textbox/userform after PrintOut command

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to develop a label printing application within Excel.

What I'm trying to do is scan a barcode and have the printer, print a label with that barcode so I can stick that label elsewhere. Problem is that the userform loses focus after the print out command and I have to click it to get the focus back and that kinda hurts productivity.

It's supposed to be able to scan and print multiple barcodes one after the other.

This is the code I have so far.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)

    Dim ws As Worksheet, cr As Long
    Set ws = Sheets("Ataque Ácido")
        cr = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    If KeyCode = vbKeyReturn Then
        ws.Range("A1").Value = "*" & TextBox1.Text & "*"
        ws.Range("A2").Value = TextBox1.Text
        ws.Range("A1:A2").PrintOut
        Me.TextBox1.SetFocus
        Me.TextBox1 = Null
    End If

End Sub
```

Suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Does the rest of it work properly?  Does it print successfully?  Either way, it probably **is** setting focus properly with `Me.TextBox1.SetFocus`, but whatever procedure called this one (or runs next) is changing it.  Interrupt the code after your `SetFocus` line to confirm.

Comment: Have you tried `Me.Hide: Me.Show`?

Comment: Added a workaround overriding the `KeyCode` parameter to prevent tab hopping.

Comment: @ashleedawg It prints the labels perfectly. The problem is that it loses focus anyway after the printout command and I don't really know why. I've done similar things in the past but for some reason, I can't seem to figure out what's wrong this time around.

Comment: @Chronocidal your method worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the code where you open the form, open it as non-modal:

```
UserForm1.Show vbModeLess
```

This stops it from losing focus and keeps it highlighted.

Comment: I already have that piece of code on the module that runs as soon as the excel file opens. Unfortunately, it still loses focus after printing.

Answer (score 0):

**Work around**

A possible Workaround is to override the resulting `KeyCode` parameter to prevent tab hopping after the `Enter` event:

**Code**

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)

Dim ws As Worksheet, cr As Long
Set ws = Sheets("Ataque Ácido")
    cr = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

If KeyCode = vbKeyReturn Then
    ws.Range("A1").Value = "*" & TextBox1.Text & "*"
    ws.Range("A2").Value = TextBox1.Text
    ws.Range("A1:A2").PrintOut
    ' KeyCode = vbKeyPageDown   ' edited: write line to bottom before End If
    ' Me.TextBox1.SetFocus      ' << original code line without effect
    Me.TextBox1 = ""
    KeyCode = vbKeyPageDown     ' << modify Enter key value to prevent from tab hopping
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your work around, but for some reason, it still loses focus after printing. Tried it just 10 minutes ago, printed a label and lost focus right after that.

Comment: @Barbaaz - just change the code line order by writing the line `KeyCode = vbKeyPageDown` after `Me.TextBox1 = ""`

Comment: @Barbaaz - did you try the corrected code in my edited answer?